# Why is object state not preserved when using Promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class ClientWrapper {
    private client: Client;

    constructor() {
        this.client = new Client();
    }

    async connect() : Promise<void> {
        return this.client.connect();
    }

    async isConnected(): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.client.isConnected();
    }
};

class Client {
    private data?: string;

    private connected: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.connected = false;
    }

    isConnected(): boolean {
        return this.connected;
    }
    
    async connect() : Promise<void> {
        this.data = 'data';
        const res = await this.executeRequest();
        this.connected = true;
    }

    async executeRequest() : Promise<string> {
        return await Promise.resolve(this.data!);
    }
};

let wrapper = new ClientWrapper();
(async () => {
    await wrapper.connect();
    console.log(await wrapper.isConnected());
})();
```

When executed, line 48 ( `console.log(await wrapper.isConnected())`) prints `true`.

Now, I modify `ClientWrapper` `connect()` method to:

```
async connect() : Promise<void> {
    this.client.connect();
}
```

, removing the `return`.

Now, line 48 prints `false`.

Why does the `connected` property of class `Client` not preserve the `true` value? Since the `connect` method returns `Promise<void>`, why does the `return` statement matter?

Thank you!

Comment: "*Since the connect method returns Promise<void>, why does the return statement matter?*" - because there's a huge difference between `return this.client.connect();` and `this.client.connect(); return Promise.resolve(undefined);`! Notice that `Promise<void>` is not the same as `void`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you call `Client.connect()` without an `await`. Therefore, the async function `Clinet.connect()` is executed while the function `ClientWrapper.connect()` has already ended. Add `await` to the invoke:

```
await this.client.connect();
```

then it will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

When you return a Promise from an async function, it will be folded into the overall Promise returned from the async function.

So when you awaited the `wrapper.connect` call you were awaiting the inner `this.client.connect` call.

When you removed the return you were awaiting the `wrapper.connect` call but it was not synchronised with the inner `this.client.connect` call. It was basically fire and forget inside the function.

You could also use `await this.client.connect()` instead of the return and the behaviour would be the same and makes more sense.